# IBAlert output of a bash script

Tags: bash, cocoa, nstask

i use NSTask to run my bash script, works perfectly, but at the end, i want the app to make an iBAlert (esay :D) but that shows a line of the bash script (ex: Pacthing hlll... Pathing dlll... Succesfully pathed dlll,hlll (whatever)). I want the "Succesfully pathed..." part in my IBAlert. is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at MFTask, a wrapper around NSTask that makes some things like monitoring output easier.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask